# PHP attempting to make JavaScript friendly timestamp, failing, returns 1.34899651119E+12

Tags: php, javascript, timestamp

Well, not sure whats going on. I have been trying to follow by examples I have found here on stack, on google, even an answer someone gave me a week+ ago, which unfortunately I wasn't able to test until today.

Anyway I am attempting to generate a javascript friendly timestamp via php so I can get my times synced up. The best logic I could find overall was something dealing with microtime. However that doesn't seem to work as expected, not even in the slightest.

Right now I am using `microtime(true)*1000;` and am getting `1.34899651119E+12` for the result. Did I some how manage to mess up that one tiny line of code, Im not sure.

I should mention that I also tried `round(microtime(true) * 1000);` which gave very similar results.

Comment: How do you use that timestamp in JavaScript; how do you build `Date` objects from it?

Comment: Eventually yes, it will be used for building dates. Right now I am just intent on storing it for later use. But I know php time functions or most of them work off of seconds since. where as javascript works off of milliseconds. Closest thing I know of in php is microtime however thats still ever so slightly off.

Comment: Besides Javascript-friendly and synced, do you also need all that precision? Both Javascript and PHP have lots of "time()" functions which work with the "Unix-time", i.e. the time in _seconds_ (not milliseconds or microseconds) since the era. They're easier to work with if you don't need high precision. Is it possible you started out with a simple question and searches led you into all that "microtime()" stuff - which is a solution to a _different_ problem and which you don't need?

Comment: Well with what I am doing, I am eventually going to have some real-time stuff, and with that I am trying to plot a course a head, so even though I don't need it right this minute. To go back and have to adjust later doesn't make sense, knowing the problem Ill face later where that level of precision to some extent will be needed. Grant it thats months off in the plans, but still I would like to cover the bases, and thats why I am looking for this solution. As I know JS tends to lean in favor of milliseconds and PHP in microtime and or seconds. So they are off a bit overall from one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is returning `1349000021801.4` to me (PHP 5.3.15 on Linux 3.4.6 x86_64).

To be on the safe side I'd bite the bullet and manipulate the microtime differently:

```
    list($a, $b) = explode(' ', microtime());
    $a = round($a*1000.0);
    $c = "$b$a\n";
```

When you output this *string* to Javascript, it *will* contain a "clean" integer.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use `Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)` to get the current time in seconds.

In PHP you can use `time` function.

Comment: Yea, I thought very similar at one point, but wasn't getting the desired results, rounding and dividing by 1000 is one thing. But trying to do the opposite doesn't give you exact. So Im trying to find the happy medium somewhere if I can